# whatsapp problem.

Tags: applications, wi-fi

I cant recieve messages on my whatsapp.
 Only one tick shows up when sending texts but the recipient receives it and but cant receive his reply.  I've tried rebooting and also its updated. 
I can see online people and change profile picture

Comment: Try clearing the cache. Settings > apps > WhatsApp > Clear data and cache

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen due to flickering data connection. Please ensure that you have stable data connection.

Also try following steps:

Go to File commander > Internal Storage > WhatsApp > Database.

Try clearing the Database folder.

This should work for you.